# How do you place a pixel at the very center of a canvas?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to place a pixel at the very center of this canvas, pic below is what happens when I select the area but I don't know now to place a 1x1 pixel at the cross section.

[image]

So how can I place a pixel at the exact center of my image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a new document with an odd number of pixels for each dimension.  Your 256x256px image won't work, as there can be no centre pixel for images whose dimensions are even numbers.

Choose the Pencil Tool, set the size to 1px

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (create a new layer)

Click once to paint a single pixel anywhere on the canvas

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (Select All)

Select the Move Tool <kbd>V</kbd>, click on the *Align Vertical Centers* button, then the *Align Horizontal Centers* button.